# angular js form validation, when loading first time

Tags: angularjs

i have a simple form with one field and submit button. I want to show error when a field is unchecked. Only issue is that for first time when page is loading it is showing error that field is required. I want to show error when form is being submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>
```

```
  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user;

});
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the span to be shown when is not pristine.

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$invalid && !myForm.user.$pristine">
```

Comment: if i have not modified any field and click on submit $pristine will return true.

Comment: That's right, pristine is false when you modify the field. If you want to apply validation only when you submit the form, you should use a variable in the scope, like hadijz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need **$pristine**: It will be TRUE, if the user has not interacted with the form yet. So when the page is loaded the required message is not shown.
2. Need to validate when form is submiited you need to check the input and show the error.

I dont know if there is a better way but for your case I have come up with this below approach.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = "";
  $scope.error=false;
  
  $scope.validate = function(){
   
   if($scope.user.length<=0)
     $scope.error=true;
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="(myForm.user.$invalid  && !myForm.user.$pristine) || error">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="bt" ng-click="validate()">
</form> 
  </body>

</html>
```